# Boolean and combining objects for 3D printing

Tags: modeling, modifiers, 3d-printing

I'm testing some tolerances between Blender 2.83 and a 3D printer I'm trying to combine a nut created with the bolt factory add-on with a cube and have the center be hollow.  How can I do this see image of problem of the center of nut not being hollowed out.  (*I tried using the Boolean modifier*)

Bolt and cube

[image: image 1]

After the Boolean operator I can't delete the face in the center of the nut see red arrow (I'm trying to hollow the nut out to test the 3D printed nut threads with a 3D printed screw)

[image: image2]

Answer (score 1):

I used the [Bolt Factory tutorial](https://youtu.be/fAyeW9Al0ME) and the [Bool tool tutorial](https://youtu.be/Rmvl0xVsA_o) ad-dons

1. Pick the object you want to use as a "drill bit" (bolt with threads)
2. Pick the item you want to drill/place the hole in (box or object) and choose `Difference`
   Note: You could also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>
   (this keyboard combination does bool difference)

[image: Animated hole create]

3. Make tolerances for bolt to screw into object

Note: you may want to 3D print the bolt horizontal for strength
[3D print the bolt horizontal for strength](https://youtu.be/-MuhSkTFp4g)

Comment: Ooh the trick for solidity is nice to know. Cheers